# Making an API call with ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to ASP.NET Core Web API and I'm trying to learn how to return a call from a News API (https://newsapi.org/). But I keep getting a 400 status code and cannot figure out what is wrong with my code so far.

```
 [ApiController]
 [Route("[controller]")]
 public class NewsController : Controller
 {
      private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

      public NewsController(IConfiguration iconfig)
      {
           _configuration = iconfig;
      }

      [HttpGet]
      public async Task<IActionResult> GetNews()
      {
           var apiKey = "top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=" + _configuration.GetValue<string>("Keys:NewsAPI");
           var url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/";

           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiKey);

           if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
                return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode);
           }

           return Ok(response.Content);
      }
 }
```

I made sure my URL is correct and that it works while debugging `HttpResponseMessage`. And followed instructions from [Asp.Net Core - Making API calls from backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404011/asp-net-core-making-api-calls-from-backend) and Microsoft docs but I'm lost here.

This is the response body I'm getting:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-fceadd8306e1d45106d330bb98529ae0-9c6374c80d070b7a-00"
}
```

Debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your API-key is correct. I tried it and it worked for me. You can test your URL string by doing this:

```
[HttpGet("UrlTest")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUrl()
{

    var apiKey = "top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=" + _configuration.GetValue<string>("Keys:NewsAPI");
        var url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/";

    return UltimateResourceFallbackLocation + apiKey;
}
```

This will give you your URL. Then simply paste it into your browser and you should get a value back.